# How to run `WP_Query` inside custom `wp_new_user_notification`?

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress I have written a custom email registration welcome email overriding `wp_new_user_notification` in a plugin. But when I try to run a `WP_Query` inside that function, query is not working. How can I call `WP_Query` inside my `wp_new_user_notification` function in the plugin? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `$post->id` was not working inside the plugin. Instead, I used `get_the_ID()` and it worked.